# How to get reducer output as a xml format in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I created a custom xmloutputformat class that translate  reducer's output into xml format.

The Problem here is the code executes successfully but the final output is in normal format instead of XML format.

Can anyone please help me out..?

```
package dd;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MaxTemperature extends Configured implements Tool {

public static class MapMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private static final int MISSING = 9999;

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        String year = line.substring(15, 19);
        int airTemperature;
        if (line.charAt(87) == '+') { // parseInt doesn't like leading plus
                                        // signs
            airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(88, 92));
        } else {
            airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
        }
        String quality = line.substring(92, 93);
        if (airTemperature != MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")) {
            context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
        }

    }

}

public static class Mapreducers extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
        }

        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));

    }

}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
    job.setJobName("MaxTemperature");

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(args[0]), conf);

    if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1]))) {
        fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
    }

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    XmlOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MapMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Mapreducers.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Mapreducers.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int xx = 1;
    xx = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperature(), args);
    System.exit(xx);
}

 }
```

The custom xmlformat code is shown below:-

```
package dd;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

 /** An {@link OutputFormat} that writes plain text files. */
public class XmlOutputFormat<K, V> extends FileOutputFormat {
protected static class XmlRecordWriter<K, V> extends RecordWriter<K, V> {
    private static final String utf8 = "UTF-8";
    protected DataOutputStream out;

    public XmlRecordWriter(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        this.out = out;
        out.writeBytes("<results>\n");
    }

    /**
     * Write the object to the byte stream, handling Text as a special case.
     * 
     * @param o
     *            the object to print
     * @throws IOException
     *             if the write throws, we pass it on
     */
    private void writeObject(Object o) throws IOException {
        if (o instanceof Text) {
            Text to = (Text) o;
            out.write(to.getBytes(), 0, to.getLength());
        } else {
            out.write(o.toString().getBytes(utf8));
        }
    }

    private void writeKey(Object o, boolean closing) throws IOException {
        out.writeBytes("<");
        if (closing) {
            out.writeBytes("/");
        }
        writeObject(o);
        out.writeBytes(">");
        if (closing) {
            out.writeBytes("\n");
        }
    }

    public synchronized void write(K key, V value) throws IOException {

        boolean nullKey = key == null || key instanceof NullWritable;
        boolean nullValue = value == null || value instanceof NullWritable;
        if (nullKey && nullValue) {
            return;
        }
        Object keyObj = key;

        if (!nullKey) {
            keyObj = "value";
        }

        writeKey(keyObj, false);
        if (!nullValue) {
            writeObject(value);
        }
        writeKey(keyObj, true);
    }

    public synchronized void close(TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException {
        out.close();
    }
}

public RecordWriter<K, V> getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext job)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Path file = FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(job);
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);

    FSDataOutputStream fileout = fs.create(file);
    return new XmlRecordWriter<K, V>(fileout);

}

}
```

--

Thanks in advance.

Comment: while debugging i came to know that the complete XmlOutputFormat class not populating.is it right way that i invoke the xmlOutputFormat in run method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

You can go through this and modify your code accordingly.

[Link](https://github.com/studhadoop/xmlparsing-hadoop/blob/master/XmlParser11.java)

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(new Text("<MapReduce>"), null);
  }


public static class Mapreducers extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (IntWritable value : values) {
     maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value.get());
}
Text out = new Text(constructPropertyXml(key, maxValue));
context.write(out, null);
  }

}
public static String constructPropertyXml(Text key, Text maxvalue) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<result><key>").append(key)
        .append("</key><value>").append(maxvalue)
        .append("</value></result>");
    return sb.toString();
  }
@Override
  protected void cleanup(Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write(new Text("</MapReduce>"), null);
  }
```

Comment: in the given link input to the map reduce job also xml but i need only output should be xml and the input is normal key value pair.. let me know if i am wrong..

Comment: Yes you can do with the same: ok can u show me ur current o/p and expected o/p?

Comment: current output : 1949 21 1950 11 expected output: <result><key1>1949></key1><value1>21</value1><key2>1950</key2><value2>11</value2></result>

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can override your RecordWriter like this. You can change the root tag, parent tag and the child tag names.

```
protected static class XMLRecordWriter extends RecordWriter<Text, IntWritable> {

private DataOutputStream out;

public XMLRecordWriter(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException
{

this.out = out;

out.writeBytes("<Output>\n");

}

private void writeStyle(String xml_tag,String tag_value) throws IOException{

out.writeBytes("<"+xml_tag+">"+tag_value+"</"+xml_tag+">\n");

}

public synchronized void write(Text key, IntWritable value) throws IOException

{

out.writeBytes("<record>\n");

this.writeStyle("key", key.toString());

this.writeStyle("value", value.toString());

out.writeBytes("</record>\n");

}

public synchronized void close(TaskAttemptContext job) throws IOException

{

try {

out.writeBytes("</Output>\n");

} finally {

out.close();

}

} 
}
```

You can also refer to the below link for more details on implementing custom output format in Hadoop. 
https://acadgild.com/blog/implementing-custom-output-format-hadoop/